# What is the correct way of generating test fixtures for use in Wagtail unit tests?

Tags: django, unit-testing, wagtail

I am trying to generate a custom page tree for testing user view permissions in the admin panel. I am dumping the fixture into a file with the following command:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary  --indent 4 > test.json
```

and using the fixture in the test case as so:

```
class MyTest(TestCase, WagtailTestUtils):

    fixtures = ['test.json']

    def test_my_code(self):
        # More code....
```

Running this test returns the following error:

```
File "/Users/jchau/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/jchau/Documents/wagtail/wagtail/tests/testapp/fixtures/test_group_restrictions.json': no such table: auth_user
```

It appears that my test data is malformed. Is there an accepted way for generating custom test fixtures for use in Wagtail?

Note: These commands are being run against a vanilla installation of Wagtail 1.8. I have not created any custom models or datatypes or otherwise made any modifications, so the only existing data is comprised of sites and pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fixture is (probably) correct - however, Wagtail's test environment is configured to use [a custom user model](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/ee837dedc55ce4f17b8c4ff9e1ae63165c509b35/wagtail/tests/customuser/models.py#L35), so a fixture created on an installation with a standard User model won't be compatible.

From a quick comparison of the two models, it should be possible to manually edit the 'auth.user' records in the fixture as follows:

- Change `"model": "auth.user"` to `"model": "customuser.customuser"
- Remove the `"date_joined"` field
- Add fields `"country"` and `"attachment"`; these can be set to empty strings

Comment: It appears that this fixed the errors with the auth_user table, but now there are problems with the UNIQUE constraint failing of wagtailcore_page.path. Are there more differences with other models? Or is the auth_user table the only one?

Comment: The custom user table is the only thing in the test setup that's non-standard at the database level, I believe. No idea what would cause failures with page path - it's worth opening a new question about that. (If your fixture contains non-unique 'path' fields on page records, something has gone badly wrong creating it...)

Comment: I figured out that it was actually a conflict with one of the initial data migrations. I've since opened an issue in the repository about either disabling migrations during testing or removing the initial page/site data so that we can use our own fixtures from the django `dumpdata` command